# Cloth physics for poly hair and armature

Tags: armature, physics, cloth-simulation, hair

I have an armature for the body and then modelled the hair. By following this tutorial (https://youtu.be/c11l2o5uCQs) on how to add cloth physics by using verts and ik modifier, the hair bangs are perfectly reacting to physic. However, when I try to connect the hair to the "head" bone of the body armature, it acts weirdly and the whole body is moving following the hair bangs.
Do I have to merge the hair armature and the body armature (if so, how to connect them) or I'm doing the wrong way :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I needed to do is to select my mesh plus the bone in pose mode and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> and set it as parent as Bone